# My.Computer.Network.UploadFile

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic, framework

VB.NET///

При попытке загрузить файл на сервер по FTP , происходит TimeoutException.

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("123.txt", "ftp://example.ru/123.txt", "login", "password", False, 500)
```

**Но главное то , что если в предпоследнем параметре указать "True" (выдавать ли окно при загрузке, мне нужно именно - скрыто ) , то всё будет работать !**

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём дело.

Comment: Задаёте такие вопросы, вы что, браузер делаете? XD

Comment: Почти )) Я пробывал раньше TimeOut 10 секунд - не работало , поставил минуту !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dfkdh7eb(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dfkdh7eb(v=vs.80).aspx)

Раздел Remarks